# segmentation fault error, assigning elements to character array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I' trying to assign elements to (nXn) character array where at the ends is "M",and on remaining of the border is "F". The error is:

> Segmentation fault :core dumped

**My code is:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    printf("Enter the size of matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *mat[n][n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) //Reset matrix
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            strcpy(mat[i][j],"0");
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) //Diagonals
    {
        strcpy(mat[i][i],"M");
        strcpy(mat[n-1-i][i],"M");
    }
    for(i=1;i<n-1;i++) 
    {
        strcpy(mat[0][i],"F");//Top border
        strcpy(mat[i][0],"F");//Left border
        strcpy(mat[i][n-1],"F");//Right border
        strcpy(mat[n-1][i],"F");//Bottom border
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to programming and don't really know why this error is occuring. Any suggestion/help ?

Comment: You need to allocate memory for mat[i][j].

Comment: Perhaps you want `char mat[n][n][2]`?

Comment: `char mat[n][n];` then `mat[X][Y] = '?';` instead of `strcpy(mat[X][Y],"?");`

Comment: Seems like you really want a 2d array of characters, not pointers, and you want to assign the values with `mat[i][j] = '0';` not strcpy.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I need to assign characters not digits.

Comment: What is the first `strcpy` in your program? Coping '0' into all of your items. I used an example from your code. `mat[x][y] = 'X';` works just fine too.

Comment: Ahh! I see.. Thank you for the reply. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not declare your matrix properly, and because of that you did not use the proper code to set it up.

If you wanted an N×N character array, not an N×N array of C strings, you should declare it without an asterisk:

```
char mat[n][n];
```

Now you can use plain assignment of character constants (note single quotes) to elements of `mat`, like this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        mat[i][j] = '0';
    }
}
```

If you wanted an N×N array of C strings, and you are OK with these strings always coming from string literals, you could use assignment in place of string copying as well:

```
char *mat[n][n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        mat[i][j] = "0"; // Double quotes are back
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to use string functions, you would need to change the array to N×N×M, where M is the longest string that you would like your matrix to hold plus one for null terminator. If all string are of a single character, the way they are in your example, the declaration becomes

```
char mat[n][n][2];
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was doing same but with double quotes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a two-dimensional array of characters you declared a two-dimensional array of pointers to char.

```
char *mat[n][n];
```

And you should not use the function `strcpy` because the two-dimensional array will not contain strings.

I think you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;

    printf( "Enter the size of matrix: " );
    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    char mat[n][n];

    memset( mat, '0', n * n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        mat[i][i] = 'M';
        mat[i][n - i - 1] = 'M';
    }

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n - 1; i++ )
    {
        mat[0][i]   = 'F';
        mat[n-1][i] = 'F';
        mat[i][0]   = 'F';
        mat[i][n-1] = 'F';
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%c", mat[i][j] );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Enter the size of matrix: 10

MFFFFFFFFM
FM000000MF
F0M0000M0F
F00M00M00F
F000MM000F
F000MM000F
F00M00M00F
F0M0000M0F
FM000000MF
MFFFFFFFFM
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```